# How to allow cursor to not become confined to one monitor in global fullscreen mode with Ubuntu 20 - i3wm

Tags: ubuntu, multi-monitor, i3, wine, steam

I am running i3wm on Ubuntu 20.04. When playing games on Steam, I'm trying to utilize both of my monitors. I use Proton which, in turn, uses WINE to run Windows games. Some games scale appropriately when entering `fullscreen global` mode in i3 but confine my mouse to the monitor in which the app originally launched.

I have tried using `wine-cfg` to disable capturing the mouse in fullscreen mode or emulate a virtual desktop of the appropriate size, but have had no success.

I'm beginning to think this is an i3wm issue rather than a WINE issue. Any help is appreciated.